# Adding a routing file inside another routing file node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want my routes to be like the following:

```
/
  /business
  /business/stuff1
  /business/stuff2
  /business/admin
```

for `/business` I want to have a separate file for the routing and functions.
and also for `/business/admin` I want to have a separate file for the routing and functions.

so what I did is:
app.js

```
//Business route
const business = require("./business/business");
app.use("/business", business);
```

This works fine - but when I add in `business.js`

```
//admin route
const admin = require("./admin");
app.use("/admin", admin);
```

I get 404 for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are exporing from `business.js`. It should be an instance of [express.Router](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router) and you have to mount the `/admin` route on this instance. Example:

```js
// business.js
const admin = require("./admin");

const businessApp = express.Router();
businessApp.use("/admin", admin);

module.exports = businessApp;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why is that tho?

Comment: Not sure why, but this is how routing in express works. You can mount a router object in another router object or the main app itself.